# MySQL, PHP and Ajax Call Until a Specific Time

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This is kind of complicated situation for me to use PHP and jQuery Ajax for presenting list of Live on going programs foe 2 hours after Now() and displaying them on the page (From the Start Time Until 2 Hours) AND after two hours display Nothing.

For example if Now() is 2014-06-12 **12**:51:00 display the

> Live Pregame = p55

Until Exactly **2014-06-12 14:45:00** (Two Hours added to the base 2014-06-12 12:45:00).

Here is the table format which I have:

```
 pName         liveTime
---------|-------------------|--
  p55    |2014-06-12 12:45:00|
  pG12   |2014-07-22 11:20:00|
  tab    |......             |
  ...    |......             |
  ...    |2014-08-07 16:30:00|
  Gong   |2014-09-18 12:45:00|
  Manc   |2014-12-16 14:45:00|
---------|-------------------|--
```

Sorry I know this is kind of complication but I hope you get my mean by this. Thanks

Comment: So do you want to use ajax from the client for 2 hours and continuously update a table?

Comment: from `12:51:00` to `14:45:00` is not really exactly two houers !

Comment: Yes Wayne, I think so, I mean I have not any better idea but how can I set the start time?

Comment: @Dwza, thanks for comment but that is the POINT , if you look at the table the actual start time is 12:45 and 12:51 is inside the time  that's why I said in the post to add time o START time

Comment: are there many times in there ? i mean... you could select all times, check them and than do you code but i would not do this if you have thousends of times saved :D

Comment: not Thousand but Hundedrs for sure

Comment: What I was brainstorming was 1- Find the Closest Past Time From liveTime 2- Check if the Diff of Now() and Result is Less than 2 Hours Then Return result, but I am confused how to do this?!

Answer (score 0):

Here is hint to help you finding you way. at least i would do it like this if I had your problem. Call the PHP file where I have an sql select like this:

```
select * from table where livetime between (now(), now()-2hours)
//echo as json
//this is pseudo code... you have to check the correct syntax befor
```

Here you may create times befor using them. Like:

```
$sql = "select * from table where livetime between ({$now},{$earliest})";
```

For received data I would do a check for the 2 houre range depending on the livetime data and than check a table to see if I already have a entry with each data, if not, append it.

Of course I would update my table from JavaScript to not have selects every second. But the ajax request would go out every 30 seconds.